# Shortest distance between line and line segment (3D)

Tags: math, geom

I found this [code](https://www.geometrictools.com/GTE/Mathematics/DistLineSegment.h) for calculate distance between line and line segment.
We are check if segment and line are not parallel and find parameters for parametric equation where distance between segment and line will be minimal. But i dont understand how we are doing this.

Сan someone explain this? Or any other explanation link of how to find distance between line and segment.

```
Result operator()(Line<N, Real> const& line, Segment<N, Real> const& segment)
        {
            Result result;

            Vector<N, Real> segCenter, segDirection;
            Real segExtent;
            segment.GetCenteredForm(segCenter, segDirection, segExtent);

            Vector<N, Real> diff = line.origin - segCenter;
            Real a01 = -Dot(line.direction, segDirection);
            Real b0 = Dot(diff, line.direction);
            Real s0, s1;

            if (std::fabs(a01) < (Real)1)
            {
                // The line and segment are not parallel.
                Real det = (Real)1 - a01 * a01;
                Real extDet = segExtent * det;
                Real b1 = -Dot(diff, segDirection);
                s1 = a01 * b0 - b1;

                if (s1 >= -extDet)
                {
                    if (s1 <= extDet)
                    {
                        // Two interior points are closest, one on the line
                        // and one on the segment.
                        s0 = (a01 * b1 - b0) / det;
                        s1 /= det;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // The endpoint e1 of the segment and an interior
                        // point of the line are closest.
                        s1 = segExtent;
                        s0 = -(a01 * s1 + b0);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // The endpoint e0 of the segment and an interior point
                    // of the line are closest.
                    s1 = -segExtent;
                    s0 = -(a01 * s1 + b0);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // The line and segment are parallel.  Choose the closest pair
                // so that one point is at segment origin.
                s1 = (Real)0;
                s0 = -b0;
            }

            result.parameter[0] = s0;
            result.parameter[1] = s1;
            result.closestPoint[0] = line.origin + s0 * line.direction;
            result.closestPoint[1] = segCenter + s1 * segDirection;
            diff = result.closestPoint[0] - result.closestPoint[1];
            result.sqrDistance = Dot(diff, diff);
            result.distance = std::sqrt(result.sqrDistance);
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: *"How are we doing this?"* is a very broad question for such a long function. Do you understand the mathematics of finding the distance from a line to a line segment? Are you comfortable with vector algebra?

Comment: @Beta I think I partially understood what we are doing. First, we find the point from the line segment that is closest to the line.
To find the closest point from a segment to a straight line, we find the nearest points between the first line and the line on which the segment lies. Next, we will check that this point lies on the segment. Otherwise, we transfer it to the beginning or end of the segment.
Next, we find a point from a line that is closest to the first point and calculate the distance between them.

Comment: Now I do not understand how we find the nearest points between two lines. I found [this](http://geomalgorithms.com/a07-_distance.html), but less computation is used in my code. What is the mathematical rationale for this?